# Create Variables based on data from an array.

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, getelementbyid, destructuring

I'd like to use data from an object to ultimately assign variables based on that string to create a getElementById selector that's also based on that string.

I'm hoping to use array destructuring to create a variables based on the items in arr with the returned items in mappedArr, but if there's a much easier way, please chime in.

I have an array of objects.

I create an array called arr.

I take the array called dataSample and map over it. When I map over it, I push element.divId into arr

I also return a template literal that fills out the right hand side of an assignment for a document.getElementById selection.

I would like to dynamically assign variables like...

```
var first = document.getElementById("first");
```

```
var second = document.getElementById("second");
```

**I've gotten this far, but I don't know what I'm missing or what to do next. Can anyone help? Thank you!**

```js
var dataSample = [
    {
        "sampleItem": "sampleItem",
        "divId": "first" 
    },
    {
        "sampleItem": "sampleItem",
        "divId": "second"
    }
]


var arr = [];

var mappedArr = dataSample.map(
  function(element) {
    arr.push(element.divId);
    return `document.getElementById("${element.divId}")`
  }  
  
);
// I would like to dynamically assign variables like...

// var first = document.getElementById("first");
// var second = document.getElementById("second");

// Etc., Etc.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  
  
  <div id="first">hey</div>
  <div id="second">hey</div>
  <div id="third">hey</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you *need* your `arr` array, or are you just trying to use that as an intermediate step to get to your `first` and `second` variables?

Comment: The `id` that you assign to an element in the markup is [already a variable](http://2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html). So you can simply access `first`, `second` and `third` without declaring them.

Comment: That's just an intermediate step. To be honest, I may be barking up the wrong tree entirely, but this was the only way i could describe what i'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First `.map` the `dataSample` array to each item's associated `HTMLElement` by using `getElementById`, and then you can destructure on the left-hand side immediately, only one line required:

```js
var dataSample = [
    {
        "sampleItem": "sampleItem",
        "divId": "first" 
    },
    {
        "sampleItem": "sampleItem",
        "divId": "second"
    }
]

const [first, second] = dataSample.map(({ divId }) => document.getElementById(divId));
console.log(first.id);
console.log(second.id);
```

```html
<div id="first">hey</div>
<div id="second">hey</div>
<div id="third">hey</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - what if you don't know how many elements you're going to have coming as objects in the array? I see you've listed first and second literally.

Comment: You said you wanted those variable names, and if that's the case, they should be hard-coded. While dynamic variable names are *possible* with `eval`, they're quite a code smell, and should really be avoided. Using dynamic *object properties* are an OK option, though.